# How do I get Image.Source from QRCodeWriter?

Tags: c#, zxing

I'm strugling a bit with old libs and can't seem to get from QRCodeWriter to a Image.Source I can put in my Image :D

I do as following:

```
QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
var bMatrix = writer.encode("FOO FOO FOO", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300);
```

But from there on I'm lost. bMatrix has a property `Array`, but this is of type zxings's `ByteMatrix` and I still need to get to Image.Source.

`WriteableBitmap` has SetSource and SetValue but I can't wrap my head around getting from `ByteMatrix`. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (got it off of pastebin: http://pastebin.com/612q0Qrb)

```
    QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    com.google.zxing.common.ByteMatrix matrix;

    int size = 180;
    matrix = writer.encode("MECARD:N:Owen,Sean;ADR:76 9th Avenue, 4th Floor, New York, NY 10011;TEL:+12125551212;EMAIL:srowen@example.com;; ", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, size, size, null);


    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(size, size);
    Color Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);

    for (int y = 0; y < matrix.Height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < matrix.Width; ++x)
        {
            Color pixelColor = img.GetPixel(x, y);

            //Find the colour of the dot
            if (matrix.get_Renamed(x, y) == -1)
            {
                img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White );
            }
            else
            {
                img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
            }
        }
    }


    img.Save(@"c:test.bmp",ImageFormat.Bmp);
```