# QRCodeWriter in Zxing in C# To Create QR code Image

Tags: c#, wpf, qr-code, zxing

Hello I want to make a image of QR code using QRCodeWriter class . Yes I can create Bar code Image using BarcodeWriter But I need to create Using QR code Writter Class I found a solution but that is very old in stackoverflow in here [QRCodeWritter Creating QR Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215637/how-do-i-get-image-source-from-qrcodewriter)  but here is a problem and the problem is
`if (matrix.get_Renamed(x, y) == -1)`
There is no method getrenamed I tried this but failed here is the method I got
[image]

Please Note that this matrix is BitMatrix matrix  from ZXing.Common.BitMatrix . How to create and solve this thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the indexer `if (matrix[x, y])`